# How do I configure a site in IIS 7 for SSL with a wildcard certificate?

Tags: iis-7, ssl, https, certificate

We have an Windows 2008 server with IIS 7 to test sites we develop for our clients. Each site has a binding on a subdomain:

1. clienta.example.com
2. clientb.example.com
3. clientc.example.com

(* Using example.com to protect the innocent)

For one of these sites we now have to test if it works over https.

---

So I have created a wildcard certificate request with *.example.com as the common name. I have received the certificate (issued by PositiveSSL SA) and completed the request. The certificate is now installed in IIS.

Now I have added an https binding to the second site with the following settings:

type: https
IP address: All Unassigned
Port: 443
Host name: clientb.example.com
SSL certificate: *.example.com

---

Browsing the site over regular http works fine. When I try to browse the site over https I get the following errors (depending on the browser used):

**Chrome**

This webpage is not available
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): Unknown error.

**Firefox**

Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at clientb.example.com
Firebug says Status: Aborted

**Internet Explorer**

Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

---

I have checked Failed Request Tracing, and according to the log the request was completed with status 200.

---

I have run the SSL Diagnostics Tool with the following result:

```
System time: Fri, 04 Mar 2011 14:04:35 GMT
Connecting to 192.168.2.95:443
Connected
Handshake: 115 bytes sent
Handshake: 3877 bytes received
Handshake: 326 bytes sent
Handshake: 59 bytes received
Handshake succeeded
Verifying server certificate, it might take a while...
Server certificate name: *.example.com
Server certificate subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN=*.example.com
Server certificate issuer: C=GB, S=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=Comodo CA Limited, CN=PositiveSSL CA
Server certificate validity: From 2-3-2011 1:00:00 To 2-3-2012 0:59:59
1:00:00 To 2-3-2012 0:59:59
HTTPS request:
  GET / HTTP/1.0
  User-Agent: SSLDiag
  Accept:*/*
HTTPS: 85 bytes of encrypted data sent
HTTPS: 533 bytes of encrypted data received
Status:
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Date: Fri, 04 Mar 2011 14:04:35 GMT
  Connection: close
  Content-Length: 315
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
  <BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
  <hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
  </BODY></HTML>
HTTPS: server disconnected
Final handshake: 37 bytes sent successfully
```

---

Q: What can I do to make this work?

Comment: I assume you purchased a wildcard cert for multi sub domains?

Comment: Correct, I have edited the title to make this more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the IP-binding to work when combined with a host header it's a good idea to first make sure the firewall is forwarding https requests to the webserver (TCP/443).

Doh.

Answer (score 2):

The 404 error in the SSL diag makes this appear as a non-SSL problem.  What error is reported in the IIS log for this request?

Comment: A 404 would make sense since the tool didn't pass a host header, and he configured a host header in the IIS config.  But I agree, the fact that it connected at all is inconsistent with the errors from the browsers..